# Module $M$ over valuation Ring $A$ is flat $\iff$ it is torsion free

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, valuation-theory

Given a valuation ring $A$ and an $A$-module $M$, I want to prove that $M$ is flat $\iff$ M is torsion free.

I already proved the implication '$\implies$' and I also know that $A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = \{0\} \cup \{a \in A\setminus{\{0\}}\; :\; a^{-1} \notin A\}$. I was given a hint that it suffices to show that every finitely generated, torsion free $A$-module is free (and thus flat); that is, every minimal generating set is linearly independent. However, I don't quite understand why it suffices to consider finitely generated modules. Could someone explain this please?

Proving the claim for a finitely generated module $M$, let $<x_1,\dots , x_r>_A$ be a minimal generating set of $M$ and $\sum_{i=1}^r a_ix_i = 0$. Since $A$ is local, by Nakayama's Lemma we have that $<\bar{x_1},\dots ,\bar{x_r}>_{A/\mathfrak{m}}$ is a generating set of the $A/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space $M/\mathfrak{m}M$. Since $r$ is minimal, the set is also linearly independent and thus $\sum_{i=1} \bar{a_i}\bar{x_i} = 0 \implies \bar{a_i} = \bar{0}$ for all $i = 1, \dots , r$. That means $a_i \in \mathfrak{m}$. Now it remains to show that $a_i$ is invertible, but how exactly can we do this?

Comment: I don't understand your sentence "Since $A$ is local, by Nakayama's Lemma ..." since what you write there holds for any quotient of any ring.

Comment: This was more precisely a corollary from Nakayama's Lemma in our class.

Comment: I think your corollary stated something different.

Comment: The corollary states: Let ($A, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring and $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module. Then:

$x_1, \dots, x_r$ generate $M$ as an $A$-module $\iff$ $\bar{x_1}, \dots , \bar{x_r}$ generate the $A/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space $M/\mathfrak{m}M$

Comment: Yes, but $ \implies$ is trivial and holds for any ring quotient whatsoever, so it is useless to apply here. Better start with a generating set of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ and apply $\impliedby$ (as in my answer) - this is really the standard procedure to apply Nakayama.

Comment: Ah my bad, I get it now. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any module is the filtered colimit of its finitely generated submodules. Also, submodules of torsionfree modules are torsionfree, *and* filtered colimits of flat modules are flat. This is why it suffices to prove that finitely generated torsionfree modules are flat, or even free.

So let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module, where $ A$ is a valuation ring. Choose $m_1,\dotsc,m_n \in M$ such that $[m_1],\dotsc,[m_n]$ is a $A/\mathfrak{m}$-basis of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$. By Nakayama's Lemma, $m_1,\dotsc,m_n$ is a generating set of $M$. We show that it is linearly independent. Assume $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i m_i = 0$ for some $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in A$. Since $A$ is a valuation ring, some coefficient $ a_j$ divides all others. If $a_j=0$, we are done. Otherwise, the relation becomes $a_j \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i/a_j \cdot m_i=0$, and since $M$ is torsionfree this implies $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i/a_j \cdot m_i=0$. But since  the $[m_1],\dotsc,[m_n]$ are linearly independent over $A/\mathfrak{m}$, we have $a_i/a_j \in \mathfrak{m}$ for all $i$, which fails for $i=j$.

A different proof, using the equational criterion of flatness, can be found in Stacks, [Tag 0539](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0539).

Answer (score 1):

> However, I don't quite understand why it suffices to consider finitely generated modules.

That's simple: every module is the direct limit of its finitely generated submodules, and a direct limit of flat modules is flat.